# How to start Liquibase migrations before MyBatis mapping in a SpringBootApplication?

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis, liquibase, dbmigrate, dbmigrator

How to start Liquibase migrations before MyBatis mapping in a SpringBootApplication?

Is it an official way for it? I tried DependsOn it doesn't work, exposing cyclic dependency

Comment: We need more information on your question. What liquibase version are you using? What type of database are you using? Can you explain more about what you are trying to do using DependsOn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liquibase has a tutorial on [how to use Liquibase with Spring boot and Maven](https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/springboot/using-springboot-with-maven.html?Highlight=spring). You could start from there.